# Windows 10 Uefi removes Ubuntu Grub after each boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, kubuntu

After installing Kubuntu, if I boot into windows 10, I can no longer see Grub and only can boot into the windows.
I reinstalled Kubuntu but the same thing happened.

Also Using Boot repair didn't fixt it :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Any help?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot into Win 10, then open *Command Line with Admin privilege* (to do so search for command in the start menu and right click and select Run as Administrator), then run the following command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

It will fix you issue, as you add grub path to windows boot manager.